# What is a signature for implicit generic function, that uses Scala macros for generation

Tags: json, scala, implicit, scala-macros

I need to serialise in JSON - sealed trait hierarchy, which looks something like:

```
  sealed trait Foo[T]
  case class Bar(x: Int) extends Foo[Int]
  case class Baz(s: String) extends Foo[String]
  case object Bah extends Foo[Void]
```

I'm using play-json-variants for this serialiati https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-variants forked to https://github.com/mavarazy/play-json-variants. I made required changes, or so I think:)

Macros signature is following:

```
object Variants {

  /**
   * @tparam A The base type of a case class hierarchy.
   * @return A [[play.api.libs.json.Format]] for the type hierarchy of `A`.
   */
  def format[A]: Format[A] = macro Impl.format[A]
```

The problem is I can't figure out what should be the signature for `implicit function`.

I've tried

```
  implicit def fooFormat[A]() = Variants.format[Foo[A]]
  implicit def fooFormat[A <: Foo[A]]() = Variants.format[A]
```

But all of them complain with trait Foo takes type parameter error.

What is correct signature for this?

Comment: `A <: Foo[A]` doesn't make any sense because if you had `Foo[Int]`, then you'd be trying to do `Format[Int]`. The type parameter should be more like `T <: Foo[_]` (doesn't work), but I'm not sure the macro can handle it.

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: It's in github https://github.com/mavarazy/play-json-variants.